# Removing "Member for"

Tags: 7, users

How can I remove the *Member for* information from appearing on accounts?
I know I can hide the field, but the problem is that Ubercart order link appears in the history field, so I can't hide the field. I have tried using CSS to hide the details, but failed as hiding the dl tag hides the whole field.

Answer (score 1):

From this [comment](http://drupal.org/node/138127#comment-5256332):

> in D7 history is a field on the user entity
>
> goto `admin/config/people/accounts/display` set the format of the
>   history field to 'hidden'

Comment: I have tried hidding the field but the problem is this also hides the ubercart 'view your order history' link, which i want to show on the account page.

Comment: What is the URL for the Ubercart account page ?

Comment: @JasmineAhmed if Ubercart conflicts with core in your use case, either ask how to deal with Ubercart or how to deal with conflict. This answer is a good answer for what you actually asked. Feel free to ask next question, about this conflict this time. by the way, you are 12 versions behind, consider upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

you remove it in this hook [hook_user_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7)

or you can  add your one .tpl. file,
and just hide it there [user-profile-category.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile-category.tpl.php/7)

```
 $profile_items
```

here you'll mess with a html_string - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620249/how-to-hide-history-section-in-drupal-user-profile-page